# Wireshark v3.05 crashing under macOS Catalina (10.15): QT library incompatibility?

Tags: macos, qt, wireshark, macos-catalina

*(Disclosure: this is cross-posted from https://ask.wireshark.org/question/12422/v305-crashing-under-macos-catalina-1015-qt-library/, but there's more activity here.)*

I just downloaded and installed v3.05 on my MacBook Pro, running macOS Catalina. Upon launching, it crashed immediately. On the console is the message:

**Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c03) with this library (version 0x50c04)**

So: what's the proper resolution? Do I / can I update my Qt library, and if so, how?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good venue for Wireshark bugs. For this one specifically, the [Wireshark Forum](https://ask.wireshark.org) is the best one, followed by sister sites superuser.com, serverfault.com, and apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RossJacobs Thank you much for the improved pointers.  (I took the presence of the wireshark  tag as an indicator this would be an appropriate place.)  Relocating...

Comment: My apologies for the confusion - what I mean is that Wireshark bugs should be directed towards the Wireshark ecosystem for the benefit of Wireshark. There are plenty of use cases where programming and Wireshark intersect like lua dissectors or leveraging Wireshark’s CLI as part of a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that a reinstall would work.

I just installed the 3.1.0 beta, to check if it worked, which it did. In order to revert to 3.0.5, I just dragged the app to the trash. Then reinstalled using the regular installer. Everything appears to work fine now.

Comment: I don't know if 3.0.5 was the problem, but 3.1.0 installed and ran fine.  Thank you for the pointer.